# Mathematical rebus: a quote

Tags: mathematics, rebus

This is a quote.

$0=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cot(7x)}}, 3562^{th} \land t\{x, y, z\}$

Some math may be required.

Hint #1:

> $\cot$ is not in quote.

Hint #2:

> You can base your thought process on this hint twice.

Comment: three thousand, five hundred and sixty twoth?

Comment: Yes, that is intended.

Comment: I don't know the answer but maybe knowing that the first equation does not have a solution helps the others.

Comment: x=0 comes close to a solution.  did Snow White do some baking that needed to be so divided?

Comment: three thousand, five hundred and sixty second, - almost ah hour ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the answer is

> "Nothing is certain except death and taxes"

$0 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cot(7x)}}$

> "$0=$" corresponds to **Nothing is**. 
>  Then the right hand side can be written as $\sqrt{\tan(7x)}$ which I think can be reformulated as "surd tan x sept" and this sounds like **certain except**.

$3562^{th}$

> Converting $3562$ from decimal to hexadecimal gives $dea$ which, when combined with "th", gives **death**

$t \{x,y,z \}$

> The canonical axes in Cartesian coordinates are labelled $\{x,y,z\}$ and so we have $t$ + axes = **taxes**

Comment: Wow, kind of curious what was the first part you got out of all of it?

Comment: I figured that $1/\cot$ must be $\tan$ and so we would be looking for a word that had "tan" in it (in some form, actually for a while I thought it would be "root tan" = rotten or something like that). I also thought about different phrases and quotes that could start like the above and it always helps to play around with the unusual number, so converting from decimal to ASCII, hexadecimal to ASCII, etc. Sometimes you get a hit.

Comment: Great answer! Although I would never have thought of reading the second part (after conversion) as "surd tan x sept".

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: surd is supposed to sound like square root?

Comment: @Ovi A square root is a surd.

Comment: Oh okay I didn't know that was a real word haha